# Is there a way to control what color seeds drop?

Tags: path-of-exile

In the new Path of Exile: Harvest league, the player collects and plants seeds for rewards. I find myself constantly out of "wild" (purple) seeds. Is there a way I can get more to drop - particular monster types for example?

Comment: Think of it differently: you get excessive drop of others. I am lazy and am just waiting until I get 24+ T1 seeds of each color and only then I am harvesting all and seeding new seeds for all. I just ignore any exceed of seeds. The "ready to harvest" message implies completely different behavior to me with much more micromanagement. Be lazy like me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tier 1, no, it's random. For later tiers, they drop of the same color as the tier 1 garden you harvested.

And don't worry too much about needing a specific seed, that need will shift as you get new gear to socket/link/reroll. Item level limits will hurt more in the short term, and in the medium term you'll have everything you need, especially once you start manufacturing T3 seeds.

Comment: I just want to add what distribution seems to be even (pseudo-random): sometimes it's less of something, but in long run it will gets even. Apart from the start, before all colors are unlocked (quest progression or level related).